# Select record group by field1 and then field2 contain each different record value of field2

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to grouping data by `field1`, and `field2` containing each different value of `field2` for each record. Maybe with model is more simple than I describe.

---

I have db like this :

```
 _____________________
|__field1__|__field2__|
|   King   |   Crown  |
|   King   |  Palace  |
```

I want to select the db so it is showing like this :

```
 _____________________________
|__field1__|______field2______|
|   King   |   Crown, Palace  |
```

For now I just grouping it by `SELECT * FROM db GROUP BY field1`.
Will be great if you can give some example in `.php` code and `codeigniter` query builder.

Sorry if I can't explain my problem best way.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use aggregation and `group_concat()`:

```
select field1, group_concat(field2) field2
from mytable
group by field1
```

Comment: If this is the resolution, then this is a duplicate question that should be closed instead of answered.  Why don't you close duplicates?